# Creating simple procedure for The Least-Square $m^\text{th}$ Degree Polynomials

Tags: fitting, polynomials, homework

I am CS major, taking Computational Numerical Analysis course. Instructor gave us freedom of choice, we were allowed to use anything or any computer language we picked, I picked Mathematica.This is my 3rd day with the program.

I am writing a simple procedure to calculate the Least-Square $m^\text{th}$ Degree Polynomials based on data sample. Algorithm is somewhat simple: http://www.efunda.com/math/leastsquares/lstsqrmdcurve.cfm
This is how far I got:

```
y_sample = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
x_sample = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8}(*Some sample data*)

f[x_] = Sum[Subscript[a, i] x^i, {i, 0, 4}](*generating polynomial, in this case, degree of 4*)    
Sum[(y_sample[[i]] - f[x_sample[[i]]])^2, {i, 0, 4}]
```

Last line of code should roughly correspond to

$$
\Pi = \sum^n_{i = 1}\left[y_i - f(x_i)\right]^2 
= \sum^n_{i=1}\left[y_i- (a_0 + a_1 x_i + a_2 x_i^2 + \ldots + a_m x_i^m)\right]^2 
= \text{min}
$$

List of problems and questions, I am facing:

1. Executing code above, produces number of errors that I don't mean much to me.
2. How do I differentiate in respect to all $\mathbb{a}_n$
3. Differentiation should produce number of linear equations, how do I set the results of differentiation to zero and solve for unknown coefficients.
4. Outputs are enormously long, is there a way to suppress some outputs !

Comment: Please DON'T USE underscoring in vriable's names!

Comment: Why ? Does it have something to do with how Mathematica interprets things ?

Comment: @user465292    Yes, see e.g. `Blank`, `BlankSequence`, `BlankNullSequence`!

Comment: I really recommend you to grab some basic language totorial and go through it, will save you a lot of trouble. Have a look at [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) for a comprehensive list of available resources.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have some errors in your syntax:

- you name your lists `x_sample` and `y_sample`, but in Mathematica, an underscore is not allowed in names (as it is reserved to patterns).
- your last sum runs from `0`, but in Mathematica, the first element in a `List` has index `1`
- your last sum should run until the number of data points, not 4
- furthermore, I would advise you to use `SetDelayed`(`:=`) in your function definition, as it prevents possible naming conflicts
- also in your function definition, letting the sum run from `0` will give problems for `x=0`, as it produces `0^0`, which is `Indeterminate`.

This gives:

```
ysample = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
xsample = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8}

f[x_] := Subscript[a,0] + Sum[Subscript[a, i] x^i, {i, 1, 4}]
result = Sum[(ysample[[i]] - f[xsample[[i]]])^2, {i, 1, Length[ysample]}]
```

Next, to calculate the derivative with respect to, say, `Subscript[a,0]`, use `D[result,Subscript[a,0]]`.

Last, to get a solution to the set of linear equations, use `Solve`:

```
sols = Solve[Table[D[result, Subscript[a, i]] == 0, {i, 0, 4}], Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, 0, 4}]]
```

To put the values of the coefficients in your polynomial, use `Replace`(`/.`):

```
final[x_] := (f[x] /. sols)[[1]]
final[x]
final[2]
```

**EDIT**

As you can see in the result, there are some values which are almost zero (10^-11 or smaller). These are simply the result of some internal round-off errors, and should of course be equal to zero. You can easily add a piece of code to discard all coefficients which are a factor smaller than the largest coefficient.

The largest coefficient is given by:

```
M = Max[Apply[#2 &, sols, {2}][[1]]
```

(don't mind the syntax too much yet, it is just a way to select the values from sols in order to be able to use `Max`on it)

Next we make the replacement for every `x` which is at least 10^6 times smaller than the maximum:

```
sols = sols/. x_ /; x < M / 10^6 :> 0
final[x_] := (f[x] /. sols)[[1]]
final[x]
final[2]
```

**EDIT 2**

It appears Mathematica has a built-in function to deal with near-zero numerics: `Chop`. It's al lot more easy to use than the method I proposed in my former edit; just write `Chop[sols]` and it will automatically thread over the rules.
Thanks J.M. for pointing that out!

Then the final code would be:

```
ysample = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
xsample = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8}

f[x_] := Subscript[a,0] + Sum[Subscript[a, i] x^i, {i, 1, 4}]
result = Sum[(ysample[[i]] - f[xsample[[i]]])^2, {i, 1, Length[ysample]}]

sols = Solve[Table[D[result, Subscript[a, i]] == 0, {i, 0, 4}], Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, 0, 4}]]

final[x_] := (f[x] /. Chop[sols])[[1]]
final[x]
final[2]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last 3 lines of code, it looks like definition is recursive. Thanks !

Comment: The first line, `final[x_] := (f[x] /. sols)[[1]]`, just defines the final function to be the function `f` (the generating polynomial) with its coefficients replaced by the solutions. I added the `[[1]]` to get rid of the extra `{}`, because the result of this replacement is a `List`.
The two other lines are just examples; `final[x]` gives the polynomial in function of `x` and `final[2]` gives the polynomial for `x=2` (the result is 20, as the function is `y=10 x`).

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write this extensive answer!

Comment: "You can easily add a piece of code to discard all coefficients which are a factor smaller than the largest coefficient." - I'd have told OP about `Chop[]`...

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't know this function (I'm not too much used to work with floating points).

Answer (score 5):

freddieknets already told you what you're supposed to be doing. Here's how I'd have done your approach to least squares:

```
n = 4;
f[x_] = Map[C, Range[0, n]].x^Range[0, n];


Solve[Thread[
    D[Total[(ysample - f /@ xsample)^2], {Map[C, Range[0, n]]}] == 0],
    Map[C, Range[0, n]]] // First // Chop
{C[0] -> 0, C[1] -> 10., C[2] -> 0, C[3] -> 0, C[4] -> 0}


f[x] /. %
10. x
```

Notes:

- `C` was always intended for indexed "arbitrary constant" use; this is one case where it certainly is useful.
- The dot product is useful for assembling a polynomial from its coefficients. An alternative is to use a "Horner approach": `f[x_] = Expand[Fold[(#1 x + #2) &, 0, Map[C, Range[n, 0, -1]]]]`
- The least-squares objective function is compactly implemented here as `Total[(ysample - f /@ xsample)^2]`; `Sum[]` is useful notationally, but in *Mathematica*, there are always other methods.
- Remember that in an optimization such as this, one is supposed to be solving for the zeroes of the *gradient*; in this case, note that `D[f[x, y, (* other variables *)], {{x, y, (* other variables *)}}]` is the way to quickly generate a gradient.
- `Thread[list == 0]` equates all the components of `list` to `0`.
- As I told freddieknets, `Chop[]` is very useful for problems such as this, when you want to treat tiny terms as actually being zero.

---

For giggles, here's one way I'd have done, if none of `Fit[]`, `FindFit[]`, `LeastSquares[]`, or `PseudoInverse[]` were available:

```
n = 4;
vm = Take[LinearAlgebra`VandermondeMatrix[xsample], n + 1];
{qm, rm} = QRDecomposition[Transpose[vm]];
LinearSolve[rm, qm.ysample].x^Range[0, n] // Chop
```

I could have used `CholeskyDecomposition[]` (the *normal equations* route), but `QRDecomposition[]` is often more numerically sound for applications like these.

There's also `SingularValueDecomposition[]`, but that requires slightly more machinery to discuss properly.

Finally, I gave a rundown of most of the usual methods for *linear* least squares in [this stats.SE answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1882); you might be interested in it.

Answer (score 3):

Also, remember you can check your results with:

```
ysample = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
xsample = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8}(*Some sample data*)
model = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d;
fit = FindFit[data = Transpose@{xsample, ysample}, model, {a, b, c, d}, x]
modelf = Function[{x}, Evaluate[model /. fit]]
Plot[modelf[x], {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> Map[Point, data]]
```

Comment: Also of interest is the `LeastSquares[]` function.

Comment: @J.M. ... or `PseudoInverse`